# Scanning from a text document

Tags: java

So I have an assignment from an online course to create a program that can scan a massive document. What this document contains is hundreds of pairs of letters that include GB GG BB BG and each set of two letters has its own line. What I have to do is figure out how many lines there are and then figure out how many of the different sets of two letters there are. I've attempted the code but I am currently stuck. The code that I have compiles but when I run it in BlueJ an output window doesn't even pop up. This is what I have so far:

```
 /**
 * This program sorts through a file and 
 * determines the composition of various families.                
 * Timothy Pierce
 * 1/2/2016
 */
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Family
{
   public static void main(String [ ] args) throws IOException
   {
      boolean isTwoBoys;
      boolean isTwoGirls;
      boolean isBoyGirl;
      int twoBoysCounter = 1;
      int twoGirlsCounter = 1;
      int boyGirlCounter = 1;

      String line = "";
      Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File  ("C:\\Users\\TEM\\Desktop\\Projects\\Family\\Document\\test1.txt"));
      while (inFile.hasNextLine ())
      {
          isTwoBoys = (line.equals("BB"));
          isTwoGirls = (line.equals("GG"));
          isBoyGirl = (line.equals("BG")||line.equals("GB"));
          if(isTwoBoys)
          {
             twoBoysCounter++; 
          }
          else if(isTwoGirls)
          {
             twoGirlsCounter++;
          }
          else if(isBoyGirl)
          {
             boyGirlCounter++;
          }
      }
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Two Boys: " + twoBoysCounter);
      System.out.println("One Boy One Girl: " + boyGirlCounter);
      System.out.println("Two Girls: " + twoGirlsCounter);
      inFile.close();
   }
}
```

I've tried for several hours but I cant seem to get it to work. I haven't even been able to count how many line there are. Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: your while loop statement is ok, I revised the comment. ill post the proper answer below.

Comment: @DanielNetzer Wouldn't you want to loop while the file has a next line?

Comment: Does `line` ever get set to anything after its initialization?

Comment: Why do the counters start from one, even before you've read anything?

Answer (score 2):

You never read the next line, so you're stuck in an infinite while loop

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you look into [Files.readAllLines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) function for this case.
It loads all the lines in a List over which you can easily iterate and do what you need.

Example: `Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\TEM\\Desktop\\Projects\\Family\\Document\\test1.txt", Charsets.default())` will load what you need

Answer (score 0):

your while loop is inifinite as stated above since inFile.hasNextLine () is a boolean statement that returns true or false but it doesnt advance the scanner to the next line, you need to add to each of the if statements a  :

```
inFile.nextLine() //advance the inputstream
```

Answer (score 0):

Skipping over the "no readNextLine" issue pointed out by others, your basic technique is terrible.

Use a Map<String, Integer>.
Store the character pair as the key.
Every time you read a new pair,
attempt to retrieve it from the map.
If you get null, then the pair does not already have a counter,
so store 1 as the value.
If you get a non-null value, add 1 and store the new count.

When finished reading,
you have a map of character pairs to number of times encountered.

Comment: I see what youre saying here and that the problem causing an infinite loop because I declare String line = "" which is the whole document so it will never work. I haven't learned the method above ye though so I'm not sure how to do that.